# DevExpress ChartControl How To Disable User Selection Zoom

Tags: charts, devexpress, zooming, mousemove

How can I disable the user selection zoom, when the user click shift and move the mouse to select area and zoom, I am using DevExpress Chart Control

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which technology you're using (WinForms, Web, WPF, ... ?), but in general setting both `EnableAxisXNavigation` and `EnableAxisYNavigation` (the diagram pane's properties) to `false` should disable the zoom.